# child theme showing all this extra information for following lines

Tags: child-theme

I created a child theme, and added all its details to the style.css file like ive done a million times, but for some reason, the child themes title is grabbing all the following child theme information that comes after

Theme Name: namegoeshere

so the title, instead of just being "namegoeshere" is "namegoeshere Theme URI: etc"

Comment: Would you please [edit](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/271328/edit) your question post the full header comment for your child theme. Also, I'd suggest that your files are encoded with UTF-8 without BOM and that they use a single type of line ending and not a mixture which can result from copying and pasting.

Comment: its just a typical one i copied and pasted off anywhere.

Comment: just copied and pasted this one https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: ill give the enconding a try